# In the solution of $x + e^x = 2$, how does $ln(W(e^2))$ become $2 - W(e^2)$?

Tags: logarithms, lambert-w

$x + e^x = 2$

1. Take $e$ of both sides
2. Apply $W(x)$ function then $\ln$ of both sides.

This gives me an answer of $\ln(W(e^2))$, but when I put the equation into Wolfram, [it gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2Be%5Ex+%3D+2) $2-W(e^2)$ as answer.

How does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x=\ln( W(e^2))$ is correct solution, then you need just take

$$2-x=e^{\ln (W(e^2))}=W(e^2)$$

$$\implies 2-x=W(e^2)$$

$$\implies x=2-W(e^2)$$

So, both are equal.

Comment: Ok I see where it comes from. But why didn't you sub in the initial $x$ in the very first line? Was it just to prove the point?

Comment: @user71207 Exactly. This proof method works by assuming that a solution $x=\ln W(e^2)$ you find is correct.

Answer (score 2):

$W(z)e^{W(z)}=z$, therefore $$e^{2-W(e^2)}=\frac{e^2}{e^{W(e^2)}}=\frac{e^2}{e^2/W(e^2)}=W(e^2)$$

Which incidentally proves that, if $W(e^2)$ exists, then $W(e^2)>0$ and $2-W(e^2)=\ln W(e^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

The $W$ function is defined so that $u=W(u)e^{W(u)}$ (for $u\ge0$). Letting $u=e^2$ and taking logs, we have

$$2=\ln(e^2)=\ln(W(e^2)e^{W(e^2)})=\ln(W(e^2))+W(e^2)$$

from which $\ln(W(e^2))=2-W(e^2)$ follows.

Comment: Ah ok. Then this is probably just something I would know through experience because wouldn't have known to "backtrack" this way to see it is indeed equivalent